# Ng file upload - url JAVA SPRING

Tags: java, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I have quick and relatively easy question I think, but I don't get it so here I am.

So, I've got something like this:

```
 file.upload = Upload.upload({
        url: 'sendemail',
        data: {file: file} 
    });
```

Whatever about rest of the code. I want to know for what is that url: section. It's for my java spring @RequestMapping("/sendemail")? Or it is for folder on my server to store the file?

Please answer me, I just want to know it :<

Comment: Url is the endpoint of your API. Since you are using Spring Annotation for mapping web requests your endpoint should be  @RequestMapping("/sendemail")

Comment: Thanks! :) That was really easy question I know, but I had to ask for sure ;)

Answer (score 1):

So when you are using Java Spring. It provides you a lots of cool annotations.
One of them is

```
@RequestMapping()
```

This annotation helps for routing your services. So when you write **RequestMapping("/sendemail")**, it looks for the end point **sendemail** and does the job accordingly.

Now to your question,
So  **{url: 'sendemail'}** specifies that the url should end with **/sendemail** so as to do the mentioned job.